# Using several image files to control an animated, or just a character in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, game-development

Basically I want to find a way to use multiple files to show an animated character moving with keyevents. I've looked for many solutions but it all seems very vague. So, so far I have

```
public class BerzerkWorld extends Application {
Random rnd = new  Random();
final private int CanvasH = 1008;
final private int CanvasW = 690;
private static final Image pWalkLeft = new Image("PlayerWalkLeft_104x40_sprite26x40.png");
private static final int pwalkLCol  =   4;
private static final int pwalkLCnt    =  4;
private static final int pwalkLOfstX =  0;
private static final int pwalkLOfstY =  0;
private static final int pwalkW    = 26;
private static final int pwalkH   = 40;

Pane playFieldLayer;
Pane GUILayer;

List<PlayerCharacterSprite> Player = new ArrayList();
List<Robut> Robut = new ArrayList();


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Pane root = new Pane();

    // create layers

    ImageView background = new ImageView("Berzerk_Level-1_Maze.png");
    final ImageView pWalkL = new ImageView(pWalkLeft);
    pWalkL.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0 , 26, 40));
    final Animation pWalkLAni = new SpriteManager()


    root.getChildren().add(background);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setWidth(CanvasH);
    primaryStage.setHeight(CanvasW);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
```

and

```
public class SpriteManager extends Transition{

private final ImageView imageView;
private final int count;
private final int columns;
private final int offsetX;
private final int offsetY;
private final int width;
private final int height;

private int lastIndex;

public SpriteManager(Pane Layer, 
        ImageView imageView,
        Duration duration,
        int count, int columns,
        int offsetX, int offsetY,
        int width, int height){
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.count = count;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.offsetX = offsetX;
    this.offsetY = offsetY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    setCycleDuration(duration);
    setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
}

protected void interpolate(double arg0) {
    final int index = Math.min((int) Math.floor(k * count), count - 1);
    if (index != lastIndex){
        final int x = (index % columns) * width + offsetX;
        final int y = (index / columns) * height + offsetY;
        imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(x,y,width,height));
        lastIndex = index;
    }
}
public void addToLayer(){
    this.layer.getChildren().add(this.imageView);
}

}
```

as a sprite manager, can some one point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/